# left join selector can't access single left table name

Tags: c#, linq

I am coding my way through the 101 linq examples, and I'm now at #106.

I am trying to rewrite query expressions in method/lambda syntax for my own learning.

Here is the example code:

```
List<Customer> customers = GetCustomerList();
List<Supplier> suppliers = GetSupplierList();

var custSuppliers =
    from cust in customers
    join sup in suppliers on cust.Country equals sup.Country into ss
    from s in ss.DefaultIfEmpty()
    orderby cust.CompanyName
    select new
    {
        Country = cust.Country,
        CompanyName = cust.CompanyName,
        SupplierName = s == null ? "(No suppliers)" : s.SupplierName
    };
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
var custSuppliers =
    customers.GroupJoin(suppliers, c => c.Country, s => s.Country, (c, s) => new { Customers = customers, Suppliers = suppliers })
        .OrderBy(i => i.Customers)
        .SelectMany(x => x.Suppliers.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, p) =>    // p is the many field (i.e. customers)
            new
            {
                CompanyName = x.CompanyName,    // no definition for CompanyName
                Country = p.Country,
                SupplierName = p.SupplierName == null ? "(No suppliers)" : p.SupplierName
            });
```

My understanding is the SelectMany takes parameters X and P where X is the "left" table (i.e. there is at most 1 of them) and P is the "right" table where there might be N of them (or a null).

But instead of the X variable holding a single customer, it holds a collection of suppliers and customers.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: Just use `Select<T>`.

Comment: As a minor improvement, you can change `SupplierName = p.SupplierName == null ? "(No suppliers)" : p.SupplierName` to `SupplierName = p.SupplierName ?? "(No suppliers)"`. The `??` is the null-coalescing operator.

Comment: Grant: Replacing the SelectMany with Select causing lambda variable to have a collection of customers and a collection of suppliers. The provided (query expression syntax) version has 1:1 instead of N:N (if that makes any sense).